# Linspace applied on array

Tags: matlab, vectorization

Given an array like `a = [ -1; 0; 1];`. For each `a(i)`, I need to compute a linearly spaced vector with `linspace(min(a(i),0),max(a(i),0),3);`, where each linspace-vector should be stored into a matrix:

```
A = [-1 -0.5 0;
      0   0  0;
      0  0.5 1];
```

With a for loop, I can do this like so:

```
for i=1:3
    A(i) = linspace(min(a(i),0),max(a(i),0),3);
 end
```

How can I achieve this without using loops?

Comment: Wolfie and @rayryeng, Given that I completely agree that this is an exact replica of the linked question. Would it not make more sense to mark the other question as a duplicate of this one as this one have more and better answers? Even though that goes against the timeline.

Comment: @NickyMattsson Duplicate answers don't go against the timeline unfortunately - even if better answers surface from recent answers.  The only thing we can do is when we move forward, we will link similar questions to this one.  Your answer is quite good, so we have that to go on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fastest way I can think of is calculating the step-size, construct the vector from that using implicit binary expansion.

```
 a = [ -1; 0; 1];
 n = 3;
 stepsizes = (max(a,0)-min(a,0))/(n-1);
 A = min(a,0) + (0:(n-1)).*stepsizes;
```

**Timeit:**

A couple of `timeit` results using (use `timeit(@SO)` and remove comments from the blocks to be timed):

```
function SO()
n = 1e3;
m = 1e5;
a = randi(9,m,1)-4;

% %Wolfie
% aminmax = [min(a, 0), max(a,0)]';
% A = interp1( [0,1], aminmax, linspace(0,1,n) )';

% %Nicky
% stepsizes = (max(a,0)-min(a,0))/(n-1); 
% A = min(a,0) + (0:(n-1)).*stepsizes;

% %Loop
% A = zeros(m,n);
% for i=1:m
%     A(i,:) = linspace(min(a(i),0),max(a(i),0),n);
% end

%Arrayfun:
A = cell2mat(arrayfun(@(x) linspace(min(x,0),max(x,0),n),a,'UniformOutput',false));
```

Then the times are:

- Wolfie: 2.2243 s
- Mine: 0.3643 s
- Standard loop: 1.0953 s
- `arrayfun`: 2.6298 s

Comment: I would recommend making one consolidated M-file that contains separate local functions for each, then just doing separate `timeit` calls on each local function inside the main M-file.  That way it avoids having to comment out whichever method you want to run and you can run all of them at once and providing timing results for all methods.  The best answers work out of box - I'm not discrediting your answer but I will admit that uncommenting the desired method and running it to observe each time result is rather annoying.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/rayryeng/27e9ca6ebe9d69784663e12325c690a1

Comment: At least uncomment the best solution (your own) to make it more obvious! I ran the same benchmark on my PC and MATLAB R2017b, with the following results: `wolfie: 0.6sec, nicky: 0.2sec, loop: 1.8sec, arrayfun: 2.7sec`. Similar, but I'm curious about the big different in loop vs mine compared to your results, perhaps `linspace` has been optimised recently.

Comment: The timings are not really a part of the solution, I was just curious which methods were the fastest, and as others might feel the same way I posted it. If you have strong opinions on how to write a timing routine for several suggestions, please just edit the answer. Regarding results, I did it on 2017a on my laptop, what I think is really interesting, is not only that your result is significantly faster, but contrary the loop is significantly slower. Which Matlab version did you use @rayryeng ?

Comment: @NickyMattsson - Windows 7 64 bit, R2016b. CPU is an Intel i7 @ 2.80 GHz with 16 GB of RAM.  My timings were: `Wolfie: 1.294659 s,
Nicky: 0.268031 s, Standard loop: 1.429961 s, arrayfun: 1.789871 s`.  Wolfie's `linspace` implementation is faster than the standard loop so my results align with Wolfie's.  As advice moving forward, whenever you provide benchmark results, it is customary to put which MATLAB version you're running, which OS you're running as well as relevant hardware specs: CPU and RAM in particular.

Answer (score 4):

Take `a = [ -1; 0; 1]`. Create the min / max array:

```
aminmax = [min(a, 0), max(a,0)].';
```

Now use `interp1`

```
N = 3; % Number of interpolation points.
b = interp1( [0,1], aminmax, linspace(0,1,N) ).';

>> b = 
      -1.0000   -0.5000         0
       0         0              0
       0         0.5000         1.0000
```

Comment: `'` for transpose? :/

Comment: @SardarUsama Assuming that the OP will only use real-values, we can overlook this but yes in general we should use `.'`.

Comment: @rayryeng I know;   :) good to see you back anyway

Comment: @SardarUsama Oh I'm around here and there :) I don't answer as much as I used to.  Also, I'm more into the Python questions now.  They're asked more frequently and the quality of MATLAB questions has unfortunately declined (save this one).

Comment: @Sardar agh you caught me! I've edited the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible solutions is to use `arrayfun` that applies a function to each element of the array. You also want to convert your results into a matrix, since the output is in the cell array. Since the output of the `arrayfun` is non-scalar, you have to turn off uniform output.

```
cell2mat(arrayfun(@(x) linspace(min(x,0),max(x,0),3),a,'UniformOutput',false))
```

Edit: I performed some testing using tic-toc method on 100000 long arrays. I found out, that the solution with `arrayfun` takes approx. 1.5 time longer than the one you suggested with for loops.

The fastest approach would be to calculate what you need using matrix-vector operation. For example, if you only need to calculate `linspace` with 3 elements, you can use something like:

```
[min(a(:),0), (max(a(:),0)+min(a(:),0))/2 ,max(a(:),0)];
```

You can generalize this method for any number of elements in linspace function (not necessarily just 3). Note that readability will suffer, as the volume of code will increase:

```
 j=4; % number of elements in each linspace
 b=zeros(size(a,1),j); % create a solution matrix of size Nxj
 b(:,1)=min(a(:),0); %first row
 b(:,end)=max(a(:),0); % last row
 temp=b(:,1)+b(:,end); % sum of the first and the last row
 for i=2:j-1
     b(:,i)=temp*(i-1)/(j-1); % fill in intermediate rows
 end
```

Note, that in this method I loop over the number of elements in each linspace, but not through the array `a`. With small j (like j=3 in your example) this will work way faster compared to the method with looping over the array `a` (if you consider large arrays like `a=rand(100000,1)`).

Comment: This is just a less readable (and possibly slower with the type conversion) version of the loop which the OP is trying to avoid...

Comment: Well, I exactly answered the question stated by OP. Readability is subjective though, as here you can write it in one line, which you cannot do (assuming conventional indents/newlines etiquette) with for loops. Where do you see a type convertion?

Comment: You actually right, my approach is a little slower. Don't exactly understand why. If you meant conversion from cell to mat under the type conversion, this is not the issue. Matlab performs it very fast (just tested on 100000 array).

Comment: `arrayfun` is a loop itself. This isn't vectorisation

Comment: @MikhailGenkin As Sardar says, `arrayfun`, `cellfun` and `varfun` are just 'loop in disguise' functions, they do one thing to each element in an array. Since [MathWorks optimised loops](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/02/12/run-code-faster-with-the-new-matlab-execution-engine/), they aren't even particularly slow, and I (subjectively) think they're more readable because the operation is usually clearer and laid out in a more pseudo-code structure.

Comment: Got it, thanks. However, I've just found out that solution using matrix-vector operations are way faster. See the edit in my post.

Comment: Your method is valid for only 3x3 matrix.

Comment: What if the OP wants to have 50 intervals, or 100? The flexibility of `linspace` is you can easily change this. I don't think your matrix operations approach is flexible.

Comment: My method with arrayfun is valid for any arrays. My method with vector-operations is valid for 3 elements linspace only. I only posted it to demonstrate one of the most efficient methods

Comment: You method with `arrayfun` is invalid because it is  a loop which the OP wants to avoid.

Comment: Well, I am not going to argue with you. Obviously, it is impossible to do it if you want to keep using linspace function since it does not support vector inputs inherently.